# Why doesn't this image blend into background in Internet Explorer (it looks fine in Firefox or Chrome)?

Tags: html, image, colors, background

I have an image that is sitting on top of a background. In Firefox and Chrome it looks fine as per below:

[image]

But in Internet Explorer (any version), it looks like the image background is a different shade than the background (I have put a red box to highlight where the image ends and the background begins, but it's pretty obvious).

How could it be that, given the same image and the same HTML background color, one browser looks fine but in Internet Explorer it looks like the colors are off as the background color of the image is a shade lighter than the HTML background?

[image]

The [full website is here](http://www.fsf60k.org) if that helps.

Comment: That IS strange. Unfortunately, I'm on my laptop and don't have all my tools here. But it appears that the background of the image itself is actually lighter on IE. Off the top of my head, I can't say what would cause that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have different image formats, and Internet Explorer got some image rendering problems. Try to put both of the images background and logo (back-page1.png, logo5.gif) in the same format either GIF or PNG (I prefer PNG) and it should do the trick!

Good luck :)

UPDATE:

So what is this render issue?

As tenfour said in comment, "assuming that the RGB color is really the same on both images, the underlying problem is that Photoshop saves gamma information in the PNG which causes Internet Explorer to render a different color than desired".

Comment: for the record, assuming that the rgb color is really the same on both images, the underlying problem is that photoshop saves gamma info in the PNG which causes IE to render a different color than desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the gamma information in the PNG. See http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/articles/png-gamma.html for an explanation of this problem. I use http://www.choppng.com/ to remove this section from the PNG.